# Get LinearLayout Gravity

Tags: android

I was needing to get the value of the gravity of a `LinearLayout`. I checked the documentation and I only found how to set it ( `setGravity(value)` ). Anyone knows if there is a way to get a `LinearLayout` gravity?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good question. I was trying to answer it myself but I couldn't. Here is what I did learn though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086486/how-to-set-both-gravity-and-layout-gravity-of-a-linearlayout-programatically/27086487#27086487

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but logically, it should work.

The problem is that the variable `mGravity`(that holds the current gravity info for the LinearLayout) is `private`. And no *accessor* methods exist to provide you access to it.

One way of solving this would be by using Reflection API.

Another (and much much cleaner) way would be to extend `LinearLayout` and override `setGravity(int)`. For instance, like this:

```
public class LinearLayoutExposed extends LinearLayout {

    // Our own gravity!
    private int mGravityHolder = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;

    public GravLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setGravity(int gravity) {

        if (mGravityHolder != gravity) {

            // We don't want to make changes to `gravity`
            int localGravity = gravity;

            // Borrowed from LinearLayout (AOSP)
            if ((localGravity & Gravity.RELATIVE_HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == 0) {
                localGravity |= Gravity.START;
            }

            if ((localGravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == 0) {
                localGravity |= Gravity.TOP;
            }

            mGravityHolder = localGravity;
        }

        super.setGravity(gravity);
    }

    // And now, we have an accessor
    public int getGravityVal() {
        return mGravityHolder;
    }
}
```

As you can tell, calling `getGravityVal()` on the custom `LinearLayout` will get you the gravity info.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. Why do you think that mGravity for the standard `LinearLayout` is private? Would people not normally need to access this?

Comment: @Suragch `Would people not normally need to access this?` I was rather surprised to find that the gravity value cannot be accessed. Surely, someone, somewhere, might need it right? But, I have been working with `LinearLayouts` (and android, in general) for over an year now. And I haven't had the need to access this value.. not even once. Its an interesting question though. Do you have a use-case that requires access to this value? Or was the bounty purely for learning purposes?

Comment: The bounty was for learning purposes, or rather, because I tried to answer the question myself and couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

#### API >= 24

getGravity ()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#getGravity()

#### API < 24

using reflection:

```
int gravity = -1;

try {
    final Field staticField = LinearLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mGravity");
    staticField.setAccessible(true);
    gravity =  staticField.getInt(linearLayout);

    //Log.i("onFinishInflate", gravity+"");
} 
catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {} 
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should get it from the LayoutParams of the LinearLayout:

```
mLinearLayout.getLayoutParams().gravity
```

@see doc of [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html):

```
public int  gravity Gravity for the view associated with these LayoutParams.
```

Comment: i've read about this in the documentation but it seems to be associated to the android:layout_gravity not the android:gravity
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html , am i wrong?

Comment: I also agree that this gets the layout_gravity rather than the gravity.